# Javascript Same object in array . Get the number of same attributes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get the number of `isUnicorn === false`. 
isUnicorn is an attribute of Poneys Object.

Better to see the code...

```
const {Poney} = require("./Poneys");

class Deadpool {

constructor(){
const poneys1 =new Poney();
const poneys2 =new Poney();
const poneys3 =new Poney();
const poneys4 =new Poney();
this.Ranch={
  "poney1" : poneys1,
  "poney2" : poneys2,
  "poney3" : poneys3,
  "poney4" : poneys4,

};
```

So how can I know how many of my poneys are not a unicorn?
I can get if they're is a poneys or a unicorn in my ranch but not the numbers...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show how you tried to solve it? You said that you can tell if there's a poney or a unicorn. How?

Comment: Go over the ponies in a loop, and simply increase a counter for every one that happens to be a unicorn …?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.keys(this.Ranch).filter( (key) => !this.Ranch[key].isUnicorn) ).length;`

Comment: Yeah, my fault. Used to ruby more )))
Fixed my answer

Comment: Thanks, man you are my god.... Unicorns are really a pain in the ***. Ps: There is an extra ")" after isUnicorn but i can't edit it.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
var numberOfNonUnicorns = 
    Object.keys(this.Ranch)
          .map(key => this.Ranch[key])
          .filter(poney => !poney.isUnicorn)
          .length;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate on your object `Ranch` and check for each poneys their `isUnicorn` property.

Something like:

```
let wadeWilson = new Deadpool();
let unicornsNumber = 0;

for (var key in wadeWilson.Ranch) {
  if (wadeWilson.Ranch[key].isUnicorn) unicornsNumber += 1;
}
```